# Using Variables with a tkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a program which a user can create his own tkinter buttons. However I have a problem with the custom name. It creates a name by storing it in a variable however it completely ignores the variable even when it is a direct variable. E.g: `variable = "TEXT HERE"`

```
Folder = open(fold2, "r")
Title = Folder.readline(1)
FolderBNam = Button(self, anchor=tk.W, text=Title, command= lambda: self.controller.show_frame(FoldButton1))
FolderBNam.place(height=55, width=75,x=25,y=100)
Folder.close
```

I have searched for answers of course and even tried to use Lamdba which didn't go so good.

Comment: Why are you doing `readline(1)`?

Comment: @AdamSmith I am trying to store the name in a txt file. So if the user restarts the program his buttons will remain there.

Answer (score 2):

The only immediate problem I see is `file.readline` shouldn't be called with an argument. That should be giving you one character rather than one line (equivalent to `Folder.read(1)`. Check my edited code below, also edited to look more like Python:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

with open(fold2) as f:
    title = f.readline()  # no argument
f_bnam = ttk.Button(self, anchor=tk.W, text=title, command=...)
f_bnam.place(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! So if i change put a 2. E.G: f.readline(2) Will it still work?

Comment: @MarsOne um, what do you think the number is doing?

Comment: @MarsOne it will if you do `readline()`, but if you do `readline(n)` it doesn't guarantee that it will read the whole line, because it will only take up to `n` characters of text.

Comment: See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline) and read carefully about the `size` argument